# How can I concatenate two mp3 files with different bit rates

Tags: php, linux, mp3, ffmpeg

I have FFmpeg installed on my linux web server.  When I execute the following code, I have intermittent results.

I think I have figured out that the MP3s do not compile when they have different bitrates.

```
exec ('cat '. $pair['source_file'] . ' ' . $pair['translated_word_file'] . '>' . $temp_mp3);
```

I might have found some articles online that reference taking them apart and then bundling them back together at a consistent bitrates.

I have confirmed that this won't really work with basic "cat" function and that "sox" can be used IF they have the same sample rate.

The issue now becomes "What is the best way to get them to the same sample rate?"

Comment: Are you talking about different sample rates or different bit rates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to find a way to strip out all of the ID3 tags and other crap, and break it down to just the MP3 stream.  Then, cut and splice on the MP3 frames.  You shouldn't leave a frame incomplete!

If you have a proper stream of frames and don't have any random data (tags) in the middle of the stream, then you should have no problems splicing files together, even if their bitrate changes!

**However!  You should probably stick to the same bitdepth (16-bit for example) and sample rate (44.1kHz for example).**  You have confused these two parameters with the output bitrate in your question.

See this:  http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html

And this:  http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm

**Edit:**  A big caveat to this is the bit reservoir.  While you can create a stream and split on frames, some data may be corrupt if the bit reservoir is in use.  I previously based this answer on my experience with a few streams.  A couple years later, I now know that you cannot reliably splice on frames for all streams.

Comment: I must admit that I am still figuring out the difference between sample rate and bit rate.  Do you have a suggested "rate" for spoken word?

Comment: would it make sense to temporarily convert the mp3 to raw format, then merge, then re-encode? Then I could assign the id3 tags at the end? I would know what the tags should be...

Comment: Sample rate is the speed at which samples are taken from the recording device.  Frequency response has a lot to do with this.  CDs are sampled at 44.1kHz.  That is, 44,100 times per second, a measurement of the pressure level is taken.  Bit depth is the resolution at which those measurements are taken.  8-bit only allows 256 levels of measurement, where 16-bit allows 65,536.  CDs use 16-bit samples.  Now the bit rate which you are referring to is the amount of bandwidth used by the codec.  The lower the bandwidth, the lower the quality of audio...

Comment: A lot of internet radio stations will use a stream of 128kbit, 44.1kHz 16-bit, stereo.  What this means is that the MP3 codec will use 128kbits per second of bandwidth to approximate the audio that was originally sampled at 44.1kHz 16-bit.  For speech, you could achieve good quality at 64kbit Mono, 44.1kHz 16-bit.  48kbit works too.  For "telephone quality", you can go down to 24kbit MONO, 22.05kHz, 16-bit.

Comment: You could convert to a raw format, do your splicing, and then re-encode.  Just remember that each time you apply a lossy codec, like MP3, you reduce your quality even more.  You'd be recompressing what is already compressed.

Comment: @Brad: I can see where if I constantly was compressing and then re-compressing, the same files, it could be a real source of deterioration.  However, I'm thinking that the worst it would be would be from mp3 (with settings as you specify), to raw, to mp3.  Then there would be a max of two iterations of "loss".... I would assume that would be a manageable loss?

Comment: @Scott, it depends on your project.  How important is quality?  If this is for dictation or something, then yes, this is fine.

Comment: @brad: Well, It would be spoken word, no music, with the exception of perhaps an a music intro or some sort of music advertisement.

Answer (score 0):

convert first the bitrate of one mp3 so that both have uniform bitrate. Then do the concatenation.

Comment: If you're already using a proper tool to open one.... might as well do the whole thing "proper-like" :-)

Comment: Reluctantly, I must admit this was the answer. I had to download them all to my server and ran them through a batch adjustment and then uploaded them back to the server. Apparently, there is a way to do this better. This would be to convert them to a "privileged format" and then combine then specify the bit rate.  However, I can't do this on my server.

Comment: After more research, I have found that this really only worked on my home machine. I'm going to have to try a more robust concatenation option.

Comment: You can have an MP3 that doesn't have a uniform bitrate.  That isn't the issue here.  See:  http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm

Comment: @Brad: The issue is that sox refuses to work UNLESS there is a uniform bitrate.  I'm working with sox these days.  When trying to use 'cat' alone, virtually no media player coould make sense of the file.